# Kivy custom widget not stacking

Tags: widget, position, kivy, kivy-language

I have made an example layout with one custom widget called DTErrorBar,

```
<DTErrorBar>:
    RelativeLayout:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 20, 450
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: col_fg
            Line:
                points: 10, 10, 10, 410
                width: 4
            Color:
                hsv: col_gn_marker_hsla
            Line:
                points: 10, 10, 10, 410
                width: 2
```

in my example, this widget contained in a BoxLayout like this:

```
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        DTErrorBar:
        Button:
        Button:
        DTErrorBar:
```

but I can't get it to stack with the buttons and the other DTErrorBar that are inside the boxLayout, this is what I'm getting:

[image]

And this what I would expect:

[image]

Now, you might ask, how did I get the image of what I expect?, It was made with a small change to the code where I use the custom widget:

```
    BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        RelativeLayout:
            DTErrorBar:
        Button:
        Button:
        RelativeLayout:
            DTErrorBar:
```

So, wrapping the DTErrorBar widget within a RelativeLayout seems to make it work, but I am not sure why, if I already have a RelativeLayout as a wrapper for everything inside my DTErrorBar widget.

In summary, what do I have to do to the definition of DTErrorBar to get the expected behavior? It would also be interesting if someone could explain what am I getting wrong here in order to learn from my mistake, thanks.

Full code for not-as-expected case: https://gist.github.com/payala/bc54f4d3d2378a97c26c9afe88858b07

Full code for not-as-expected case: https://gist.github.com/payala/9de4de166c7c1942cc923c32550bf661

### Edit: Modification After jligeza's answer

In the python side, the DTErrorBar class was declared like this:

```
class DTErrorBar(Widget):
    pass
```

Which was creating the custom widget derived from the base *Widget* class. Changing to inherit from a Layout class solved it:

```
class DTErrorBar(RelativeLayout):
    pass
```

By doing this, it also no longer makes sense to have a RelativeLayout inside the widget definition, since the widget is itself a RelativeLayout, so the final widget definition code becomes this:

```
<DTErrorBar>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 20, 450
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: col_fg
        Line:
            points: 10, 10, 10, 410
            width: 4
        Color:
            hsv: col_gn_marker_hsla
        Line:
            points: 10, 10, 10, 410
            width: 2
```

Comment: What kind of widget is DTErrorBar?

Comment: It is a custom widget that I am creating, the first block of code in the question shows how it is defined. Possibly something wrong there.

Comment: If it's not a layout type widget, then all its content is going to be placed at pos=[0,0].

Comment: Haha, I just figured it out right now, in effect, it is derived from Widget, by deriving from RelativeLayout it gets fixed, and I can remove the parent RelativeLayout inside my custom widget too. Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: Yes, I will post an answer to make it easier to read for future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DTErrorBar` should subclass some layout widget, for example a `RelativeLayout`. If you subclass a simple `Widget`, then it has no idea how to position its children (here: the relative layout with a canvas), so it sets all their positions to the window's [0, 0].